# Navigate to tabview's subview from another tabview's subview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have:

```
TabView {
  ViewA()
  ViewB()
}
```

In ViewA I have a SubViewA() and

In ViewB I have a SubViewB()

**How** do I navigate from SubViewA() to **SubViewB()** using NavigationLink (or other solution) ? and have SubViewB() a back button that navigates to **ViewB()**

This is what I have so far:

**ViewA()**

```
struct ViewA: View {
  NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(destination: SubViewA()){}
  }
}
```

**SubViewA()**

```
struct SubViewA: View {
  NavigationLink(destination: SubViewB()){}
  .isDetailLink(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SubViewA`:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ViewB(toSubView: true)) {
    Text("Navigate")
}
```

In `ViewB`:

```
struct ViewB: View {
    @State var toSubView: Bool
    var body: some View {
        //Content...
        NabigationLink(destination: SubViewB(), isActive: $toSubView) {
        }.hidden()
    }
}
```

Or;

Now for multiple view just add your view to the Master `Enum` and the subviews to the Sub Enum. And for navigating use the navigate function with or without `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`. [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dsep.jpg)

```
 struct SubB: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation() {
                    navigation.navigate(to: .subViewC)
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Sub View C")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Sub B"))
    }
}


struct SubA: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation() {
                    navigation.navigate(to: .subViewB)
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Sub View B")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Sub A"))
    }
}

struct SubC: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation() {
                    navigation.navigate(to: .subViewA)
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Sub View A")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Sub C"))
    }
}

struct C: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SubC(), tag: Sub.subViewC, selection: $navigation.subView) {
                    Text("Sub View C")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("View C"))
        }
    }
}

struct A: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("A")
                NavigationLink(destination: SubA(), tag: Sub.subViewA, selection: $navigation.subView) {
                    Text("SubView A")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("View A"))
        }
    }
}

struct B: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("B")
                NavigationLink(destination: SubB(), tag: Sub.subViewB, selection: $navigation.subView) {
                    Text("Sub B")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("View B"))
        }
    }
}

struct Root: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $navigation.selected.int) {
            A()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "capsule.portrait.fill")
                    Text("A")
                }.tag(Master.viewA.rawValue)
            B()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "capsule.fill")
                    Text("B")
                }.tag(Master.viewB.rawValue)
            C()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "capsule")
                    Text("C")
                }.tag(Master.viewC.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

class Navigation: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selected = Master.viewA
    @Published var subView: Sub?
    func navigate(to sub: Sub) {
        withAnimation() {
            guard let master = Master.init(rawValue: sub.int) else {return}
            selected = master
            subView = sub
        }
    }
}

enum Sub: Equatable {
    case subViewA
    case subViewB
    case subViewC
    var int: Int {
        switch self {
            case .subViewA = 0
            case .subViewB = 1
            case .subViewB = 2
           //here when adding subsubsubViews, it's value must be equal to it's master view i.e subsubViewA = 0
        }
    }
}

enum Master: Int, Equatable {
    case viewA = 0
    case viewB = 1
    case viewC = 2
    var int: Int {
        get {
            switch self {
                case .viewA:
                    return 0
                case .viewB:
                    return 1
                case .viewC:
                    return 2
            }
        }
        set {
            switch newValue {
                case 0:
                    self = .viewA
                case 1:
                    self = .viewB
                case 2:
                    self = .viewC
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but in the second solution, after navigating to the SubB, the tabview is still in A whereas it should in B

Comment: And if you wanna keep ViewA in SubViewA just remove presentationMode from the button

Comment: Yes, now it works. But I m still looking to make it closer to real use cases. Let's say you have SubSubSubView what's the best way to deal with this? keep passing the binding variables?

Comment: Also how do you solve this when you have 5 tabs? You declare 5 boolean variables??

Comment: Yes you can keep passing the binding variable or if in the future you have multiple variables it would be best to create an ObservableObject Class and use it as an environmentObject. Please accept it as a correct answer if you find it helpful!

Comment: Runnin it is throwing this error in the line: TabView(selection: $navigation.selected.int) {
Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Navigation found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Navigation may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

Comment: Yes you must add  .environmentObject(Navigation()) when calling Root view

Comment: how to make it working when having subsub..Views ? like here https://app.codingrooms.com/w/G7SpntPWnd15

Comment: or maybe using this library https://github.com/Bahn-X/swift-composable-navigator#swift-package what do you think ?

Comment: I don't know about the library, you can try it and see if it fits the goal you're trying to achieve, but in the code you added, the subsubsub view must have a rawValue exactly equal to the one of it's master View i.e View A = 0 -> subviewA = 0, subsubViewA = 0. And that's because it'll use this Integer to set the selected Tab. In addition, because in Enums you can't have the same raw value for 2 cases, you can add a new variable and use switch to assign the corresponding Int value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235749/discussion-between-noeonjupiter-and-a-akrm).